# Best way to verify email via mobile app

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile-application, email-verification

What could be the best to verify email for a mobile app? Can be iOS or Android app. It's too much trouble for user to go back to email app and then be redirected to browser and then verify there and return all the way to open their mobile app. Is there any easier way to reduce the functionality and increase the smooth flow of the app?

Comment: if not absolutely necessary for some reason, just leave it out if you only provide a mobile app without web interface.

Comment: What do you mean by verify email? Do you want to verify the email address is in correct format or not?

Comment: I am sure you are verifying email to create unique user account for your app right?

Comment: I already have a web app, in which I'm verifying user's email id. I'm sending a link to them using mail and they'll have to visit the link to verify their email id. That's it.

Comment: @Prajeet.. I'm verifying email in my web app, sure. But if a user registers via mobile app. What is the best to verify there is my question.

Comment: This is a good question - I'm not sure why people are down voting it

Comment: Thanks @DerekTomes 
It's a lifetime ago now. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OAuth 2 authorization for your app. And use Google, Facebook, or other OAuth Resource providers. It's the most easy and foolproof method of managing users in your app. On top of that, you could access many more pieces of information of users using the SDK provided by Facebook and Google.

Comment: I'm not using any external Auth. I've my own web-app which will be connecting to the mobile app via api I created for that purpose. And so far, I've not added any social logins.

Comment: Okay! I don't think there's any better to do it. There must be two way communication for a user to be verified. Cutting it short is not an option.